# ffmpeg "-pix_fmt yuv420p" option when streaming on Youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

The official tutorial https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide uses the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` option.

I used it too, copied it from the tutorial, and streaming from FFmpeg to Youtube works for me. However, it is not clear what it is for, and especially if it is a necessary option with Youtube, or if there is a better one.

The Youtube documentation on the subject doesn't seem to cover this, or maybe it does but I haven't understood where: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en.

Does anyone know of any accurate documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YUV420 is a color space that uses chroma subsampling to reduce the amount of data needed to represent an image. Chroma subsampling is a method of encoding images by implementing less resolution for chroma (color) information than for luma (brightness) information. This takes advantage of the human visual system’s lower sensitivity to color differences than to brightness differences. **As a result, YUV420 can be considered a space-saving format because it requires less data to represent an image compared to formats that do not use chroma subsampling**.

**Regarding my question about using `-pix_fmt yuv420p` when streaming, I found an answer that is both general and specific to YouTube.**

The FFmpeg streaming guide linked in my question (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) uses the H.264 codec via the `-vcodec libx264` option. This is also the codec suggested in YouTube's official recommendations (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en#zippy=%2Cvideo-codec-h).

**The specific answer for YouTube can be found in that documentation, in the sentence**:

> "Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0".

**This corresponds exactly to the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` option**.

The general answer can be found instead in the FFmpeg documentation for H.264: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264. At the bottom of the page it says:

> You may need to use `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) for your output to work in QuickTime and most other players.
> These players only support the YUV planar color space with 4:2:0
> chroma subsampling for H.264 video. Otherwise, depending on your
> source, `ffmpeg` may output to a pixel format that may be incompatible
> with these players.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are looking for is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

YUV is effectively the video format here.

And from my understanding it only describes pixels/colors, so it's also effectively uncompressed. Aka you are explicitly communicating color data pixel by pixel without any of the typical trickery that leads to an 1080p image not being several megabytes large.

For streaming I recommend using OBS (https://obsproject.com/de). It is open Source and uses ffmpeg too, because everything video does. OBS will handle the parameters pretty well and it is effectively the industry standard.

Since you posted under Unix&Linux:
OBS is available via standard package sources for many typical distributions.